# use if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `if` in javascript. I used the `if` condition as I mentioned below. But is incorrect. why is it wrong. and how can I solve it?

```js
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
  var $originals = tr.children();
  var $helper = tr.clone();
  $helper.children().each(function(index) {
    $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
  });
  return $helper;
},

if (window.confirm("Do you really want to update the order?")) {
  updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
    $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function(i) {
      $(this).html(i + 1);
    });
  };
}

$("#table tbody").sortable({
  helper: fixHelperModified,
  stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: *"why is it wrong"* -- it is invalid syntax: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'`. Presumably you mean to use a semi-colon and not a comma after your `fixHelperModified` definition.

Comment: The first thing to do whenever JS code doesn't behave as you expect, check the console for errors.

Comment: why is there a `,` after the function? A good linter hooked up to your IDE would have caught the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the `','` in Line 8.